# jQuery Photo Gallery Bug if mouse moves fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

This is a very weird bug, my code is most probably correct, since it works in most cases except when mouse is moving around on elements very fast.

Here is my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .fadeto {
            opacity:0.4;
            position:box;
        }
        .selected {
            opacity:1.0;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:gold;
        }
    </style>
```

Here is my html body:

Click over the images to toggle their permanent visibility. Or click here to toggle them all:
    Toggle

```
<div style="margin:50px;">
<img class="fadeto" src="nature.jpg" /><!--you can change the source-->
<img class="fadeto selected" src="nature.jpg" /><!--by default selected, just not to waste time selecting elements-->
<img class="fadeto" src="nature.jpg" />
<img class="fadeto" src="nature.jpg" />
<img class="fadeto" src="nature.jpg" />
<img class="fadeto" src="nature.jpg" />
<img class="fadeto" src="nature.jpg" />
<img class="fadeto" src="nature.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Here is my jQuery script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fadeto').hover(function(){
                    $(this).fadeTo(100, 1);
                },function() {
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
                        $(this).fadeTo(100,0.4, function(){
                            $(this).removeAttr('style'); //removed IF not selected
                            document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML +=$(this).attr('style');
                        });
                    else {
                        $(this).removeAttr('style'); //removed IF selected
                        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML +=$(this).attr('style');
                        }
                })
            .click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                });

            $('#Toggle_Button').click(function(){
                $('.fadeto').toggleClass('selected');
                });
});
</script>
```

Whenever I move the mouse around the images in normal speed, with no rush, everything works perfectly. But whenever I try and move the mouse over the elements fast, it causes a bug with the Toggle button: Some elements remain with opacity 1.0.

I remove the style attribute after each animation is finished, because I don't want any element to stay with style="opacity:1;", since it would overwrite any conflicting CSS Class Rule that is applied to the element.

I have included the feedback `<div>`, so that I can keep track whether the style attribute is removed or not, and yes, no matter how fast the mouse moves, the code inside there is executed, and style is undefined.

Also, I know that stylesheets are read from top to bottom, so I have included the 'selected' class after 'fadeto', since its opacity rule has more priority than the other's.

If there is a problem with my code, please help me? Otherwise, what can I do? What do you suggest?

Comment: When you move the mouse around quickly, does your feedback say that the style attribute is still there, or do you still get 'undefined'?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the problem with a debugger? Chrome debugger will show you the html element and all of the style associated with it.

Comment: first time i hear that :D. sorry i am new at this. should i download anything or it is within chrome already? if so how to access it?

Comment: View->Developer->Javascript console. Once you have the debugger open, go to the 'Elements' tab and you can see all the html elements in your page, and you can watch the style values change as jQuery runs. On the right you can see the css being applied to each individual element. For lots more details, see the Chrome debugger documentation at https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: thanks a lot for showing me this feature. I tried it out and it was great. So, i tried again moving the mouse around pretty fast and found out that the style in the selected elements remained. While if i hovered normally it disappeared. I don't understand, what could i do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem, so it's hard for me to suggest a fix. Try posting your code (all of it) to jsFiddle. If you can reproduce it there, then I can perhaps suggest a fix.

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly suggest hoverIntent when you play around mouse over and mouse out

```
$(selector).hoverIntent({
    over: function(){},
    out: function(){},
    selector: '.selector'
});
```

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Hope this helps

Comment: it seems good idea. but how could implement the same effect just with jquery library, without plugins? maybe with a javascript setTimer or jQuery delay? thanks

Comment: yes the logic is to delay sometime before executing, go through the plugin and try to find your way out, but i think it would be better to use the plugin as you might need it several times

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, giving a code snippet which might give a quick idea is comment!!!!! really strange

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem before and found that using mouseenter and mouseleave rather than mouseover and mouseout solved the issue

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.